# When connecting with xrdp connection crashes/closes [from w10 to u20.04]?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, xrdp, rdp

If I installing xrdp and use Windows (I also tried different devices) RDP to connect it crashes. If I have Xfce installed it connects normally and force uses it over gnome/default envoirnment and skips the log in screen but some functionality is broken.

How would I fix this? I have tried reinstalling the desktop environment, purging xrdp, using an installation scrypt...

If I can't fix it: I remember using it normally before reinstalling Ubuntu. Is there any better alternative that is also compatible with Windows rdp.